# How do I catch statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint FK

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

[image: statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint]

I will like to know how to catch the exception for this error message. 
I tried to delete a record from a table, but the table has a FK from another table.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: check ex.Message.ToLower().Cotains("statement conflicted with the reference constraint") and throw custom error message to end user's understandable.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more information.  I'm assuming based on the context, you're looking to identify the record that has a FK constraint in a multiple row delete?  What environment is this occurring? You can profile to see what's hitting the DB, you could debug to get the list of `StreetIds` attempting to be deleted, and then query the FK table with those IDs, etc.  Or do you mean literally catch the exception so you don't do a YSOD?  To what end? What are you hoping to accomplish rather than not showing this error page?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
try
{
     //Your code block to delete the record.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("statement conflicted with the reference constraint"))
     {
          //Show custom error message as "need to delete parent value before delete this record."
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Balagurunathan but the query is from sqldatasource used in a gridview.